# ASP.NET - Centralized background jobs server for multiple web sites

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks, newsletter, hangfire, background-service

I am trying to find the best way to add background services for all our sites.
We run over 2000 sites and for each site there can be plenty of processes that should run in the background, for example:

- Sending massive bulk newsletters
- Scheduled tasks for maintenance
- Sending SMS and mails when something happens
- Create image thumbnails
- Much more

I would like to centralize the background jobs for each web site in the IIS.

I tried to use Hangfire but it was difficult to implement over so many sites, using only one database.

I would not like to have a job manager database for each site.
A single server that handles all the jobs is our goal. Maybe two servers, one for maintenance and another for sending bulk newsletters.

We work on ASP.NET Web Forms, with SQL Server over IIS.

I don't want to implement the whole thread logic by myself. I want to use a robust framework.

What do you recommend is the best framework to do such a thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to use Hangfire but it was difficult to implement over so many sites, using only one database." ?

Comment: I tried Hangfire, but couldn't understand the best practice for connecting thousands of sites with background job services. Should it be a single server and database for each site, or a centralized server with a database for all the sites together? In the first case, there would be a separation between the background jobs but the resources are too high - a server for each site with its own database. The second case would centralize all the sites background jobs in one place, but then will be hard to know which job comes from where. And if the server goes down, all the sites would be affected

Comment: You can have as many servers as you want with the same DB. However a thousand sites seems a lot. Maybe split them on several databases (categorize them?)?

Comment: Yes, that is what i thought. I will probably will have to create several centralized servers that have an own database. Each of the servers will supply background services to a specific amount of sites.

I really don't know how, for each server, separate the jobs inside so I can know from which of the sites the request came. Maybe by creating a different queue for each site? I don't know if it is correct, because there may be hundreds of queues for each site.

or other solution may be to create a single queue that receives all the sites' requests and I send the siteID as a parameter

Comment: We are entering design/architecture here and you will have to make choices. I suggest you start with something and come back if you face problems

Comment: Yes, of course. I wanted to understand before implementing anything if there were any basics that I need to know.

Because all the examples are small scale scenarios I wanted to know from someone's experience if there are limitations or performance issues while increasing the project's scalability